# How to trust an internal Root CA in Azure App Service

Tags: ssl, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function calling an HTTPS endpoint using an SSL certificate that was provided by an internal Root CA.
Without doing anything, I have an SSL negotiation error which is normal.

I added the ROOT CA cert in the SSL Settings of my Function App, and I also added the setting WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES in the Function App Settings.

By using the Kudu Console, I tried to curl my HTTPS endpoint, and I'm still having SSL troubles.
Am I missing something?

Comment: You can refer to this article: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/06/22/Root-CA-on-App-Service-Guide.html. Looks like it is only supported for ASE tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an internal authority signed certificate against an Azure Function that is in a multi-tenant environment. The only available approach is to use App Service Environment (ASE). Using ASE, will enable you to upload an issuing and root certificates that are signed by a private/internal authority and register them in the store to be able to be interrogated.

Answer (score -1):

Try to follow the below steps to enable SSL.

1. Go to `App service` and then select `TLS/SSL` settings.
2. Click on `Private Key Certificates` and then click on `Create App Service Managed Certificate`. It opens a side window in that window click on `create button`.
3. After successfully created, go to `custom domains` and click on `Add binding`.
4. Under TLS/SSL binding, select `custom domain` name, `private certificate thumbprint`, and its type then click on `Add Binding`.
5. Once we finished the above steps then it will add to your domain.

As per the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex,portal#create-a-free-managed-certificate), Add a TLS/SSL certificate in Azure App Service.

Comment: You are here talking about the creation of a custom domain, this is not the right way to trust a root CA.